# Are all class 40 errors normal in serializable transactions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Some of my transactions are declared as SERIALIZABLE.  Sometimes I get back class 40 errors such as `40001 serialization_failure` and `40P01 deadlock_detected` (I haven't seen other codes yet), particularly when I'm stress testing the system by doing lots of concurrent transactions.

If I understood the manual correctly, this is to be expected.  When these errors happen, I'm therefore suppose to retry the transaction.  My doubt is whether **all** of class 40 errors are "normal" when handling SERIALIZABLE transactions.  In other words, can I just assume that any class 40 error should lead me to retry the transaction, or is this assumption correct only for a subset of class 40 errors?

Comment: What version of Postgres are you on?

Comment: I'm on PostgreSQL 9.1.  Though I'll update to 9.2 as soon as Ubuntu 13.04 packages are available.

Answer (score 9):

Per [the error codes section of the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/errcodes-appendix.html) the `40xxxx` `SQLSTATE` category is "transaction rollback".

It includes the error codes:

- `40000`   transaction_rollback
- `40002`   transaction_integrity_constraint_violation
- `40001`   serialization_failure
- `40003`   statement_completion_unknown
- `40P01`   deadlock_detected

Of these, I would not generally expect `transaction_integrity_constraint_violation` to trigger a retry, since that'll be raised when a `DEFERRED` foreign key check causes a transaction to abort when commit is attempted. This is unlikely to go away if retried unless your application has issues with concurrency and locking design.

I haven't encountered `statement_completion_unknown`; I'd suggest looking it up.

Personally I would retry on `deadlock_detected` and `serialization_failure` only.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Though you don't seem too sure that checking only for 40001 and 40P01 is really the correct approach.  I'm looking for a more categorical answer...

Comment: @JonSmark As I'm not seeing references to these sqlcodes elsewhere in the docs you might have to take a look at the sources. I'm not able to do so right now; time requirements from other projects.

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime, Kevin Grittner gave me [an unequivocal answer](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1368066680.60649.YahooMailNeo@web162902.mail.bf1.yahoo.com) in the pgsql-general mailing list.  To summarise, both errors 40001 and 40P01 are "normal" when issuing serializable transactions in a concurrent setting.